# How do I connect ASP.NET login with my table?

Tags: asp.net, authentication

How do I connect ASP.NET login with my table?

I have this table:

```
CREATE TABLE [T_USERS](
    [ID]            INT IDENTITY(1,1) NOT NULL,
    [NICKNAME]              VARCHAR(300) NULL,
    [PASSWORD]              VARCHAR(300) NULL,
    [FIRSTNAME]             VARCHAR(250) NULL,
    [LASTNAME]          VARCHAR(250) NULL,
    [EMAIL]             VARCHAR(250) NULL,
    [IP]                VARCHAR(250) NULL,
    [CREATED]           DATETIME DEFAULT(GETDATE())

    PRIMARY KEY ([ID])
    )
```

I need to connect the login and registration to my table.

Comment: please elaborate... IMO, "How do I connect ASP.NET login with my table?" is very vague

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is a solution that helped:

**Custom Membership Providers:**

**LogOn.aspx**

```
<asp:Login ID="Login1" runat="server" BackColor="#F7F7DE" BorderColor="#CCCC99" BorderStyle="Solid"
                        BorderWidth="1px" Font-Names="Verdana" Font-Size="10pt">
                        <TitleTextStyle BackColor="#6B696B" Font-Bold="True" ForeColor="#FFFFFF" />
                    </asp:Login>
```

**CustomMembershipProvider.cs**

```
public class CustomMembershipProvider : MembershipProvider
{

    public override bool ValidateUser(string username, string password)
    {
        User user = new User();
        UserObj userObj = user.GetUserObjByUserName(username, sha1Pswd);
        if (userObj != null)
            return true;
        return false;
    }

}
```

**Web.config**

```
<connectionStrings>
    <add name="ApplicationServices" 
      connectionString="Server=your_server;Database=your_db;
                         Uid=your_user_name;Pwd=your_password;"
      providerName="System.Data.SqlClient" />
</connectionStrings>

<authentication mode="Forms">
  <forms loginUrl="~/Account/LogOn" timeout="2880" />
</authentication>

<membership defaultProvider="CustomMembershipProvider">
  <providers>
    <clear/>
    <add name="CustomMembershipProvider" 
        type="CustomMembership.Models.CustomMembershipProvider"
        connectionStringName="AppDb"
        enablePasswordRetrieval="false"
        enablePasswordReset="true"
        requiresQuestionAndAnswer="false"
        requiresUniqueEmail="false"
        maxInvalidPasswordAttempts="5"
        minRequiredPasswordLength="6"
        minRequiredNonalphanumericCharacters="0"
        passwordAttemptWindow="10"
        applicationName="/" />
  </providers>
```

**More here:** http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/165159/Custom-Membership-Providers

Answer (score 0):

You will need the asp.net login view control please see link how to do http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.webcontrols.loginview.aspx

and here is a very nice example showing databinding http://asp-net-example.blogspot.co.uk/2008/10/getallusers-method-example-how-to-get.html